# can't generate a Random value?

Tags: vba, random

I´ve made a code on visual basic for a wind calc. but can't run a random value, as the results are not random. I´ve run it twice just to check if values are random but not at all. Lot of time working on this code and need some help pls

Please see my code below (if you spot others mistakes, please let me know, much appreciate)

```
For j = 1 To n_p
    ti = 0
    For i = 0 To n_t
        ti = delta_t * i
        Sum2 = 0
    
        For m = 1 To j
            Sum1 = 0
            For l = 1 To n_f
                w_lm = (l - 1 + m / n_p) * delta_w
                C = Exp(-lbd * w_lm * delta_L / (2 * Pi * U_m))
                
                If j < m Then
                    G = 0
                ElseIf m = 1 Then
                    G = C ^ Abs(j - m)
                ElseIf m <= j And m >= 2 Then
                    G = C ^ Abs(j - m) * Sqr(1 - C ^ 2)
                End If
                
                fu = L_u * w_lm / (2 * Pi * U_m)
                S = 4 * fu * S_v ^ 2 / (w_lm * (1 + 70.8 * fu ^ 2) ^ (5 / 6))
                                
                fi = Rnd() * 2 * Pi
                
                Sum1 = Sum1 + Sqr(S) * G * Cos(w_lm * ti + fi)
            Next l
            
            Sum2 = Sum2 + Sum1
        Next m
        
        Vi = Sqr(2 * delta_w) * Sum2
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement

Comment: Please provide the the variable contents for testing

Comment: use  Randomize before the rnd function

Answer (score 0):

To add to the link @braX posted: here's also the link to the [Rnd()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function) function, as it's explained there why the random number presumably isn't random: "*For any given initial seed, the same number sequence is generated because each successive call to the Rnd() function uses the previous number as a seed for the next number in the sequence."*

I.e. *Without* the `Randomize` statement, the seed for `Rnd()` is *always the same* and therefore the pseudo random number sequence is *always be the same*.

As counter-intuitive as that sounds, this is in fact a mandatory requirement for *every* Pseudo Random Number Generator. And that's basically **every** RNG implemented with a software algorithm.